# programa Python para verificar se um número é um número de Armstrong

Tags: python

Olá, estou tentando escrever um programa Python para verificar se um número é um número de Armstrong, mas estou recebendo um erro no meu código. Alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar problemas e corrigir o erro no meu código para verificar os números de Armstrong em Python? Aqui está meu código atual:

```
def isArmstrong(num):
digits = [int(d) for d in str(num)]
return sum([d**len(digits) for d in digits]) == num

print(isArmstrong(153)) # should return True
print(isArmstrong(123)) # should return False
```

A saída que estou obtendo é "True" para ambas as entradas, mas deve ser "True" para 153 e "False" para 123. Alguém pode me ajudar a entender o que está causando esse erro e como corrigi-lo? Agradeço antecipadamente por sua ajuda.

Comment: Seu código retorna o resultado esperado: https://ideone.com/RoP1f8 (claro, arrumando a indentação que está errada na pergunta).

Answer (score -2):

Testei aqui e seu código realiza o teste corretamente (retornando True para 153 e False para 123). Mas há um erro de indentação na função isArmstrong que impossibilita sua execução.

Corrigindo esse erro seu código ficará dessa forma:

```
def isArmstrong(num):
    digits = [int(d) for d in str(num)]
    return sum([d**len(digits) for d in digits]) == num

print(isArmstrong(153)) # should return True
print(isArmstrong(123)) # should return False
```